# HttpContext Request Files Count is coming zero

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

I am trying to get a picture from the user and upload it to a folder in my application. But, my file count is coming out zero in my Web API. Due to this, I am unable to upload it to the folder.

I am working in AngularJS along with an MVC Web API Controller.

My input control is:

```html
<input type="file" valid-file upload="uploadFile(file)" ng-model="file">
```

The directive is as follows:

```javascript
app.directive('validFile', [function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { format: '@', upload: '&upload' },
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
            // Change event is fired when file is selected
            el.bind('change', function (event) {
                console.log(event.target.files[0]);
                scope.upload({ file: event.target.files[0] });
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(el.val());
                    ngModel.$render();
                });
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

The controller method is as follows:

```javascript
var PromiseData = UserService.uploadProfilePicture(file);

PromiseData.then(function (Response) {
    alertify.alert('Picture Uploaded Sucessfully');
    $scope.ProfilePicturePath = response.data;

}, function (Error) {
    alertify.alert('Some issue occurred while saving picture');
});
```

Service method to call Web API as follows:

```javascript
this.uploadProfilePicture = function (ProfilePicture) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', ProfilePicture);
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/ImageUploadApi",
        data: formData,
        headers: { "Content-Type":false }
    });
    return request;
};
```

The image upload API to upload a file is as follows where the *HttpContext.Current.Request.Files* count is coming to *zero*.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace UAECensus.Controllers
{
    public class ImageUploadApiController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post()
        {
            var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/UserProfilePic/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

            // Fetch the file name.
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

            // Save the file.
            postedFile.SaveAs(path + fileName);
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, fileName);
        }

    }
}
```

Also, I have added the following line in *WebApiConfig.cs* in the *AppStart* folder:

```csharp
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you checked with `headers: { "Content-Type":multipart/form-data }` ??

Comment: Re *"AngularJS"*: [AngularJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) is ancient. Do you mean [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework))?